# Selenium prints empty innerHTML/innerText of an element

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

With Selenium, why does the following function print empty string? Same if I try `'innerText'` instead of `'innerHTML'`.

`send_keys` part works fine though.

```
def button_clicked(self):
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.get('https://www.google.com')
        search_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
        search_box_HTML = search_box.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        print(search_box_HTML)
```

Comment: Can you sum up your _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: This code is just to put the print statement in some context.  What I am interested in is why does `inner`HTML` and `innerText` not work with Python in Selenium. For example, when automating IE through VBA I can print `innerHTML` with `getAttribute("innerHTML")` without a problem.

Comment: Won't comment about `innerText()` but `getAttribute("innerHTML")` is proven, powerful and working when used in proper context. However I don't understand the line/xpath `find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Szukaj']")` from your code while I can't see the context of  `textbox` in your code as well.

Comment: I have removed the 'textbox' line as irrelevant to the problem. `find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")` locates the input box on Google. I want to print its `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the *HTML* of the page [`https://www.google.com`](https://www.google.com) and inspect the ***Search Box*** *WebElement* which you have identified as :

```
find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
```

The *WebElement* is defined as follows :

```
<input class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" aria-label="Search" aria-haspopup="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" style="border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: none;">
```

### **`get_attribute("innerHTML")`**

As per the documentation, [*Element.innerHTML*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants and [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.get_attribute) is defined as follows :

```
    def get_attribute(self, name):
    """Gets the given attribute or property of the element.

    This method will first try to return the value of a property with the
    given name. If a property with that name doesn't exist, it returns the
    value of the attribute with the same name. If there's no attribute with
    that name, ``None`` is returned.

    Values which are considered truthy, that is equals "true" or "false",
    are returned as booleans.  All other non-``None`` values are returned
    as strings.  For attributes or properties which do not exist, ``None``
    is returned.

    :Args:
        - name - Name of the attribute/property to retrieve.

    Example::

        # Check if the "active" CSS class is applied to an element.
        is_active = "active" in target_element.get_attribute("class")

    """
```

Hence, as the *WebElement* i.e. ***Search Box*** doesn't have a descendant, so **`get_attribute('innerHTML')`** returns **empty**

Comment: @barciewicz Upvote this/any Answer which is/was useful to you for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2):

An `<input>` has no inner content—text or HTML. Instead, the data entered by the user is stored in its `value` attribute, which can be retrieved with `WebElement#get_attribute()`:

```py
search_box.get_attribute(“value”)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to:

```
search_box.get_attribute('value')
```

That should do the trick